# How to open new Screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In my react native project I have BottomTabNavigation with 5 bottom tabs but i want to add new screens not a tab (like login,signup, change password ,cart,sign out  ) but i dont know  how to do this , can anyone tell me how this will happen. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my app screenshot  https://ibb.co/4fqgXwp

Comment: Did you create BottomTabNavigation with [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) library ?

Comment: Yes I have created bottomTabNavigation but I want to used stack navigation inside it.

Answer (score 1):

React Native doesn't provide a navigation solution as robust as you're asking for. Take a look at `react-navigation` for a solution that should be easy to follow and meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**You should use Stack Navigator as your main navigator . Add Bottom Tab navigator as stack navigator scene**

**Code For AppNavigator React Navigation**

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tab1: Tab1,
  Tab2: Tab2,
  Tab3: Tab3,
  Tab4: Tab4,
  Tab5: Tab5
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: TabNavigator,
  Login: Login
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**Working Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) library as mentioned in [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation).

Comment: I am totally new in React Native can you explain in brief here please